# worker.properties file configuration for cluster

Tags: apache, tomcat7

After going through some docs specially [tomcat help page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics).
 I have used this configuration of FarmWarDeployer to configure two tomcat
nodes as part of Cluster.

```
1: tempDir="\temp-dir\"
        deployDir="\webapps\"
        watchDir="\watch-dir\"
        watchEnabled="true"/>

2: tempDir="\temp-dir\"
        deployDir="\webapps\"
        watchDir="\watch-dir\"
        watchEnabled="false"/>
```

Configuration folders are respective to two TOMCAT_BASE instances
1: C:\tomcat1
2: C:\tomcat2
My TOMCAT_HOME is C:\tomcat7.

The 1st tomcat is able to deploy the war correctly from watchDir folder as
evident from log below(added smileys for imp lines):

```
    1     startInternal
2     INFO: Cluster is about to start
3     Jul 17, 2017 3:48:08 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase
4     bind
5     INFO: Receiver Server Socket bound to:/192.168.1.8:4000
6     Jul 17, 2017 3:48:08 PM
7     org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl setupSocket
8     INFO: Setting cluster mcast soTimeout to 500
9     Jul 17, 2017 3:48:08 PM
10    org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
11    INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start
12    level:4
13    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:09 PM
14    org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
15    INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:4
16    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:09 PM
17    org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
18    INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start
19    level:8
20    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM
21    org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
22    INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:8
23    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer start
24:)    INFO: Cluster deployment is watching [\watch-dir\] for changes.
25    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer start
26:)    INFO: Cluster FarmWarDeployer started.
27    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve
28    startInternal
29    INFO: JvmRouteBinderValve started
30    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
31    deployDescriptor
32    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor
33    C:\tomcat1\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
34    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
35    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
36    debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
37    but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can
38    improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
39    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
40    deployDescriptor
41    INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor
42    C:\tomcat1\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml has finished in 785 ms
43    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
44    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
45    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
46    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
47    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
48    INFO: Server startup in 3077 ms
49    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer
50    fileModified
51:)    INFO: Installing webapp [/catalogue] from [C:\tomcat1\webapps\catalogue.war]
52    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
53:)    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\tomcat1\webapps\catalogue.war
54    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
55    validateJarFile
56    INFO:
57    validateJarFile(C:\tomcat1\webapps\catalogue\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar)
58    - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class:
59    javax/servlet/Servlet.class
60    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
61    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
62    debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned
63    but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can
64    improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
65    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager
66    startInternal
67    INFO: Register manager /catalogue to cluster element Host with name
68    localhost
69    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager
70    startInternal
71    INFO: Starting clustering manager at /catalogue
72    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager
73    getAllClusterSessions
74    INFO: Manager [/catalogue]: skipping state transfer. No members active in
75    cluster group.
76    Jul 17, 2017 3:48:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
77    INFO: Deployment of web application archive
78 :)   C:\tomcat1\webapps\catalogue.war has finished in 359 ms
```

My Question is :
1: why automatic deployment is not happening in second node.
2: MoreOver, How the second node will know about the deployed war if
*watchEnabled
*is *FALSE.*

Tomcat: 7.0.79
Apache: httpd-2.4.26-Win64-VC15
with mod_jk, thanks in advance.